# Expand RStudio preview data

Tags: r, rstudio

I'd like to hear how one could bypass the default `View()` options. In my computer it only shows up to 100 columns. I'd like it to about 400 columns. It's possible?

Comment: I don't see an option to change that in `help(View)`.  You can see them all in `edit()` though

Comment: edit() doesn´t seems to work this function can only deal with factors and numeric vectors, I do have a lot of character variables.

Comment: Are you sure?  I did `iris[[5]] <- as.character(iris[[5]]); edit(iris)` and it worked okay.

Comment: It's not currently possible with the RStudio native data viewer. RStudio uses the DataTables library, which struggles with large numbers of columns, so we capped it at 100 to head off performance issues. We're hoping at some point to add virtualized columns to make this better but it's a large project so may not get immediate attention.

Comment: @Jonathan Ok, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, you can use the `utils::View()` to view more columns of the data.  This isn't quite as useful or pretty as the RStudio Viewer but it does a decent job on tables with more than 100 columns.

The other option that I occasionally use is `View(df[,101:200])` etc. to view different columns of the data--sometimes this can be combined with some columns at the beginning so that I can see the necessary key data.